# jQuery Not working on my site, but works on my browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Running into a problem on my site that I just tried hosting, for some reason, the jQuery code that I have written is working in my browser before I hosted it via HTTPS, but when I am trying to use it via the actual site, the jQuery is not responding. The image that is clicked is supposed to bring the document back to the top of the image when it is clicked. Here is the link to the site"
https://www.andrewswanson94.byethost7.com/KiloArt/visions.html

Comment: "Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.andrewswanson94.byethost7.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID"

Comment: "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.andrewswanson94.byethost7.com/KiloArt/visions.html?ckattempt=1' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

by
`<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

The error is due to mixing HTTP and HTTPS

Its best practive to use `//` instead of http ot https so that you don't need to worry about the protocol

Comment: have you updated the website so i can check what else is wrong

Comment: Sorry, i misclicked the file, it worked perfect, thanks alot!

Answer (score 3):

Console tells you the exact problem:

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://www.andrewswanson94.byethost7.com/KiloArt/visions.html?ckattempt=1'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
>   'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

You can not mix http and https

Comment: So the solution would be to access a library over HTTPS source?